# Change value inside a loop on Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a question about how can I use different values in each iteration with a loop. I have an image with 145 bands. I calculate the size, the number of rows, columns and bands

```
size=size(HYP);
nrow= size(1);
ncolu= size(2);
nbands= size(3);
```

I have to do an operation for every band, and then obtain the result but I don't know how to change  one of the values automatically for every iteration. I'm going to try to simplify the question. This is my loop. The value rad1 is defined before. I need that on every loop uses some value defined before (for example, band2 value rad2, band3 rad3...) and extract a result for each one (nd1 changes automatically to nd2, etc.)

```
output= zeros(nrow,ncolu,nbands);
for banda=1:nbands;
      nd1= -((3.141592*rad1)/-HYP2(:,:,1));
output(banda,1)= (nd1);
    end
end
```

So, for the first iteration:

**nd1**= -((3.141592***rad1**)/-HYP2(:,:,**1**));
    output(banda,1)= (**nd1**);

for the second...

**nd2**= -((3.141592***rad2**)/-HYP2(:,:,**2**));
    output(banda,2)= (**nd2**);

Rad1,rad 2... rad145 etc is defined before. And at the end, output would be a 145 band matrix.

Do you know how can I do it? Really thanks in advance,

Comment: Make nd and rad a vector? So you have nd(banda) and rad(banda). Or use a cell array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try using different variable names. Just use `rad(1)`, `rad(2)` etc. and then

```
output= zeros(nrow, ncolu, nbands);
for banda=1:nbands;
   output(:,:,banda) = -((3.141592*rad(banda))/-HYP2(:,:,1));
end
```

(Your initialization of `output` doesn't match the code in your loop, by the way.)

Comment: Hi Cristopher and thanks for your quickly reply. The problem is that rad1, rad2, etc are a variable defined before with different values. So, for example, for the first band, I need to use the rad1 value, for the second rad2, etc.

Comment: Change the code that defines these variables. Seriously. Such variable names are just asking for trouble. (Still, the MATLAB FAQ will tell you how to use them if you absolutely must.)

Comment: Thanks Christopher for your help. I'm going to try it! ;)

Comment: +1 for convincing the OP to modify his existing code instead of just presenting a simple work-around for his problem (in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899155/change-value-inside-a-loop-on-matlab#comment22640793_15899273). Give a man some code and you help him with a problem. Teach a man to program and you help him for a lifetime...